# Authenticating app with Google Vision API

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I'm trying to upgrade my app to google-cloud-vision:1.35.0 but I can't authenticate with my api key.

Previously it was as simple as adding my key to the method before calling it. It went something like this :

```
VisionRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new VisionRequestInitializer(CLOUD_VISION_API_KEY);
```

I don't think there's a method like that anymore. I was trying to run the steps here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
,including creating a service account and using that export command to export the json to my project.

And yet, I still keep getting the same error :

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information

Is there a simpler way to add my authorize my app? Whether it be with my api key or with the service account json. I've been stuck on this for several days.

Answer (score 0):

Application Default Credentials are not available on **Android**.
 But they are currently available for **python**, **c#** and **web version** only
 Use an API key to easily authenticate your requests to the Cloud Vision API.
 This might help [Cloud Vision Android](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/android)

Hope it helps.

Comment: That project uses version 1.23.0
The current version 1.35.0

I was previously succesful authenticating on 1.23 the same way as we see in the demo project. But that method is not available in 1.35.0